# Converting Silverlight application to Silverlight class library

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, build-automation

In my Visual Studio 2010 solution I have a Silverlight application project and a hosting ASP.NET project.
Now I have added a new Silverlight application project hosted in the same ASP.NET project. I want to convert the old Silverlight application project to a Silverlight class library project, and be able to use it from the new application project by on-demand assembly downloading.
For this I need the class library project be built every time the ASP.NET project is built and the resulting DLL be copied to the respective ClientBin folder.

So my questions are:

1) How to convert an existing Silverlight application to a Silverlight class library?
2) How to host a Silverlight class library project in a ASP.NET project, i.e. how to make the DLL file be copied to the ClientBin folder of the hosting project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First unload the silverligh application. Then edit the .csproj file.

Look for

```
  <SilverlightApplication>true</SilverlightApplication>
```

and set it to:

```
  <SilverlightApplication>false</SilverlightApplication>
```

Save, reload and that's all.